# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'salesforceSoapApi'

Tags: python-3.x, rest, salesforce

To use Rest api in python 3.7 for salesforce, i used below code to import the package

```
'''python code'''
import salesforce
```

I am getting below error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'salesforceSoapApi'
```

I have installed saleforce python sdk.

```
pip install salesforce-python-sdk
```

Comment: from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

Comment: That library hasn't been touched in 5 years. Consider instead using a newer or more actively maintained library, such as [`SalesforcePy`](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforcePy) or [`simple_salesforce`](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by say and david .. below worked

first install simple_salesforce

```
pip install simple_salesforce
```

and then in python file add below code at the top

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
```

Try this